# 2 Column tabular with automatic line-wrapping

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I am trying to have a 2 column table (this is the only section with 2 columns in my entire document). Since some lines are too long i would like them to wrap (this part works). However, this causes blank lines on the rows wil short text (e.g. first row - left-hand col is only 1 line but right-hand column is 2). How do i edit this elegantly such that it is wrapped and the empty spaces are gone. Worst case would be the split the rows manually and put them on separate rows. The image below shows the example of the line that i want moved up.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.05\textwidth}  p{0.4\textwidth} p{0.05\textwidth} p{0.05\textwidth}  p{0.4\textwidth}}
\underline{\textbf{Sets}} &&& \underline{\textbf{Parameters}}\\
$\mathcal{V}$ & set of customers && $\delta_{trc}$ & Penalty for flow from scenario $t$ to scenario $r$ for cluster $c$\\
$\mathcal{S}_v$ & set of schedules for customer $v$ && $Q$ & Maximum capacity of vehicle\\
$\mathcal{T}_c$ & set of target demand scenarios for cluster $c$ && $\underline{q}{}_v$ & Minimum delivery quantity for customer $v$\\
$\mathcal{R}_c$ & set of demand scenarios for cluster $c$ && $D_v$ & Total demand of customer $v$ over all periods\\
$\mathcal{C}$ & set of clusters && $D^{CMI}$ & Total average daily CMI demand\\
$\mathcal{K}_c$ & set of customers in cluster $c$ && $\xi$ & Proportion of total average daily CMI demand to set aside in fleet\\
\underline{\textbf{Variables}} &&&$\underline{q}{}_{crv}$ & Lower bound of demand for customer $v$ in scenario $r$ of cluster $c$\\
$d_{vs}\in\{0,1\}$ & Customer $v$ served using schedule $s$ && $\overline{q}_{crv}$ & Upper bound of demand for customer $v$ in scenario $r$ of cluster $c$\\
$q_{vp}\in\{0,1\}$ & Delivered amount to customer $v$ on period $p$ && $\pi_{tc}$ & Target fraction of days of scenario $t$ for cluster $c$\\
$x_{vpk}\in\{0,1\}$ & Customer $v$ delivered in period $p$ using vehicle $k$\\
$y_{crp}\in\{0,1\}$ & Scenario $r$ of cluster $c$ occurs in period $p$\\
$f_{trc}\in\mathbb{R}$ & Optimal \emph{flow} from scenario $t$ to scenario $r$ for cluster $c$\\
$\Pi_{rc}\in\mathbb{R}$ & Fraction of days of serving scenario $s$ for cluster $c$\\
\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you employ two side-by-side two-column `tabularx` environments, with widths of `0.57\linewidth` and `0.43\linewidth`, respectively. By making the left-hand `tabularx` environment wider than the right-hand one, the overall lengths of the `tabularx` environments can be made roughly equal.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % suspend full justification

\begin{document}

\begingroup % localize scope of next three instructions
\small      % 10% linear reduction in font size
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}      % default: 6pt
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % default: 0pt
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{0.57\linewidth}[t]{@{} >{$}l<{$} L }
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\textbf{Sets}} \\
\mathcal{V}   & set of customers \\ 
\mathcal{S}_v & set of schedules for customer $v$ \\ 
\mathcal{T}_c & set of target demand scenarios for cluster $c$ \\ 
\mathcal{R}_c & set of demand scenarios for cluster $c$ \\ 
\mathcal{C}   & set of clusters \\ 
\mathcal{K}_c & set of customers in cluster $c$ \\[1ex]
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\textbf{Variables}} \\ 
d_{vs}{\in}\{0,1\}     & Customer $v$ served using schedule $s$ \\ 
q_{vp}{\in}\{0,1\}     & Delivered amount to customer $v$ in period $p$ \\ 
x_{vpk}{\in}\{0,1\}    & Customer $v$ delivered in period $p$ using vehicle $k$\\
y_{crp}{\in}\{0,1\}    & Scenario $r$ of cluster $c$ occurs in period $p$\\
f_{trc}{\in}\mathbb{R} & Optimal \emph{flow} from scenario $t$ to scenario $r$ for cluster $c$\\
\Pi_{rc}{\in}\mathbb{R}& Fraction of days of serving scenario $s$ for cluster $c$\\
\end{tabularx}%
\begin{tabularx}{0.43\linewidth}[t]{ >{$}l<{$} L @{}}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Parameters}} \\
\delta_{trc}       & Penalty for flow from scenario $t$ to scenario $r$ for cluster $c$\\
Q                  & Maximum capacity of vehicle\\
\underline{q}_v    & Minimum delivery quantity for customer $v$\\
D_v                & Total demand of customer $v$ over all periods\\
D^{\mathrm{CMI}}   & Total average daily CMI demand\\
\xi                & Proportion of total average daily CMI demand to set aside in fleet\\
\underline{q}_{crv}& Lower bound of demand for customer $v$ in scenario $r$ of cluster $c$\\
\overline{q}_{crv} & Upper bound of demand for customer $v$ in scenario $r$ of cluster $c$\\
\pi_{tc}           & Target fraction of days of scenario $t$ for cluster $c$\\
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: 0.57 and 0.43 were determined specifically for this instance. Is there a way to automatically do this or make it line-wrap nicely with 50-50 split on widths

Comment: @Abilash - You asked, "Is there a way to automatically do this?" Not that I know of. Of course, there's absolutely nothing stopping you from using a 50-50 split; in fact, that's how I got started. I noticed that with a 50-50 split, the left-hand table was a lot longer than the right-hand table, largely because there were quite a few line breaks with very little material on the continuation line. So I switched to 55-45, which looked a lot better, and then I tried 57-43, after which I decided to declare victory. Do note the presence of the `\small` directive, by the way.

Comment: Could you please explain the changes you made to the code? Primarily what do all the alignment arguements at the end of each tabularx and multicolumn line mean? Also, how did you make it such that the 2 separate tabularx tables were side by side instead of above and below? thanks

Comment: @Abilash - `\begin{tabularx}{0.57\linewidth}` means: "Start a `tabularx` environment with a target width of `0.57\linewidth`". `[t]` means "top-alignment" (relative to whatever else is on that row)". `{@{}` means "no left-hand whitespace padding"; `>{$}l<{$}` means "left-aligned natural-width column in automatic inline math mode" (that way, you don't have to inserts lots of `$` symbols manually to initiate and terminate inline math mode); and `L` means, according to its earlier definition, *viz.*, `\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}`, an `X`-type column without full justification. (continued)

Comment: @Abilash - (continued). The `tabularx` package defines the `X` column type; it is a `p`-type column for which LaTeX calculates the appropriate width. In practice, the width of an `X`-type column is calculated as a residual, once the widths of all natural-width columns and all intercolumn whitespace is subtracted from the target width (which was `0.57\linewidth`). The `tabularx` columns are placed side by side because I didn't provide an all-blank line between them. Recall that an all-blank line in TeX and LaTeX code creates a paragraph break.